# Адаптивный контент в BorderPane

Tags: java, javafx

Всем доброго!

Есть некий `workerDashboard.fxml`, в нем BorderPane. В левой части основные кнопки (идея заключается в том что при нажатии кнопок надо меняться содержимое в центре).

Что я делаю: при нажатии на кнопку срабатывает такой эвент:

```
public void show_dashboard_invoice(MouseEvent event) throws IOException {
        Parent dashboard = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("contents/invoicePage.fxml"));
        borderPane.setCenter(dashboard);
    }
```

Все нормально, вот только проблема в том, что пока не совсем понимаю, как делать автосайзинг центрального...

Спасибо за ответы! )

[image: вот то что получаю на больших мониторах]

Comment: Слишком мало данных, что бы понять что требуется. В центральную часть впишется ваш invoicePage, он не будет больше чем установлен максимальный размер у центральной области, а она не будет больше чем максимальный размер borderPane.

Comment: это так и есть но invoicePage остается не динамическим

Comment: добавил скриншот...

Comment: Последнее время мне все больше нравится AnchorPane, с помощью него очень легко прибить таблицу к краям и сделать фиксированный отступ сверху для названия.

Comment: А да, что бы внутренний Pane был равен меняющейся центральной области потребуется что-то вроде:         ((AnchorPane) dashboard).prefWidthProperty().bind(borderPane.widthProperty());

Comment: можете чуть подробнее, где писать? где borderPane.setCenter(dashboard)?

Comment: да, dashboard это и есть рутовая pane из вашего invoicePage, их размеры можно связать

Comment: извините что туплю, но 
borderPane.setCenter(((AnchorPane)dashboard).prefWidthProperty().bind(borderPane.widthProperty()));
получаю: setCenter in BorderPane cannot be applied to (void)...